# 960gs based Wordpress theme floats to left

Tags: css

I m using 960gs grid system for one of the websites i have been building. Everything looks perfectly fine on all browsers but in the blog section page elements floats to the left.I have been trying to pinpoint what might be the problem but unable to find the answer. Here is the link to the blog section http://bit.ly/vfsAOp.

Comment: What part of the blog element? It looks centered. Can I get a screenshot?

Comment: Please provide some more specific information.

Comment: You have to view it on Internet explorer 7 or 8. Here is the screenshot of when i view it on internet explorer 8. Problem is only in wordpress theme when viewed by ie 7 or 8. Screenhot of the image http://imgur.com/Dg19b

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but try adding position:relative; or maybe overflow:auto; to the containing parent (header, footer or possibly .container_12).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to ask why is there a big left margin next to the blog articles which are floating left ...

If yes, its because you used the class "push_1" on these elements. Just remove it and it will be fine.

Comment: No it was intentional. The problem was solved after i included modernizr.js at header section.